Alternatives to IF function
I have this formula -  ((F29-((F29*((100-H25)/100))+(D29*0.5))) where F values are input H 25 is input and D values are input (F and D are from Data and H25 is manipulable.
I get an answer, However It is sometimes negative. With the nature of what I am doing the answer can NOT be negative. Only Positive or 0 if  <=0. As a result i developed this If formula -
IF((F29-((F29*((100-H25)/100))+(D290.5)))>0,(F29-((F29((100-H25)/100))+(D29*0.5))),"0")
which works well.
I have data sets of F27-F36 and D27-D36. So 10 of the above formulas are daisy chained to give me and answer ie IF((F30-((F30*((100-H25)/100))+(D300.5)))>0,(F30-((F30((100-H25)/100))+(D300.5))),"0")+ IF((F29-((F29((100-H25)/100))+(D290.5)))>0,(F29-((F29((100-H25)/100))+(D29*0.5))),"0")  + etc
I want to know what H25 is when the sum of those 9 formulas = 30.0. I Am unaware of a viable way to make H25 the subject of that equation.
Are there any better ways I can Get only a positive or 0 result without using an if formula-   My end goal is to have 30.0 as my answer and given the fact that D and F values are constant find H25.
Right now I am unable to do this due to the complexity of the IF.
Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly helpful.
To clarify I have D27-36  F27-26  and I know D25 which gives me an answer. My desired answer is 30.0, I need to find H25. I can do it easily with trial and error, but I want it automatic.
Many thanks !!

Your problem isn't explained well enough to be sure but looks like the sort of thing that the Solver toolbox was designed to solve. It will quite happily let you set some cell to a particular value (or minimise/maximise it). File, Options, Addins Solver ought td do it.

Looks to me as if this is a job for the Goal Seek add-on. See https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9506732
